# Задание метатаблиц строкам

Tags: lua

Как известно, при помощи `setmetatable` можно задать метатаблицу только таблицам. А как быть с другими типами даннных, например со строками? Судя по докуметации lua -- никак, только через C. Хорошо, а как же `ffi`? Но и там проблема -- нельзя получить `Lua_state`. А `ffi.metatype` работает только с `cdata`.

В общем: как задать метатаблицу чему-нибудь кроме таблиц (не используя C кроме `ffi`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getmetatable"".__call = print
local str = "abc"
str()

debug.setmetatable(nil, {__index = function() end})
local t = nil
print(t[1])
```

Comment: Хм. Только с дебагом?